# How can I make an image become an embedded video on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So today I learnt how to change an image to a different image on mouse over.

I'm wondering though, can I change an image to a youtube video on mouse over?

Comment: You can, but you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can replace any HTML content you wish. To make it easier to deal with the event handlers (the mouse over in your case), I advise you take a look at some existing Javascript libraries, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: can you give me an example please?, Im trying to change this image: http://i.imgur.com/sjSSr.jpg 
into this video: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlEkvbRmfrA

but im quite new to javascript (i know html,css)

Comment: There are some HTML content replacing examples here: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ - for your specific case, you would add the image to the page, then have a `mouse over` event handler bound to that `img` element. This would then trigger the `replaceWith` method of jQuery to replace it with an embedded youtube video

Comment: Another solution is given below, where you display the image (using CSS) on top of the youtube video. Then the `mouse over` event should call `hide` on that `img` tag (still assuming you will go for using jQuery) ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and some CSS:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3SQtS/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="replacement">
    <img class="top-img" src="http://placekitten.com/560/315" alt="Kitten">
    <iframe class="video" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/H93n-k3SkiQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

---

```
/* CSS */
.replacement {
    position: relative;
}
.top-img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

---

```
// jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.replacement .top-img').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```